# Can't find referenced method

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am getting this error after trying to generate my apk

> Warning:com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base: can't find referenced method 'boolean equals(java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor)' in program class javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor

i can run my code to a device but not generating an APK

Comment: Can you post your graddle file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this in the `Proguard` part of the `gradle` file:

```
-dontwarn java.awt.**,javax.activation.**,java.beans.**
```

Comment: This merely hides the Proguard warning - and does NOT FIX the underlying problem. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850304/android-proguard-and-javamail) for clarity on this issue - that is if you got this error while trying to use the JAVA Mail API.

Answer (score 1):

As @SilSur comments, the chosen solution only hides the Proguard warning but doesn't prevent runtime errors due to missing classes. After some trial-error I found that this Proguard configuration works OK preventing any runtime problems:

```
# JavaMail
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.activation.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-keep class javamail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.mail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.activation.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.** {*;}
-keep class mailcap.** {*;}
-keep class mimetypes.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.awt.datatransfer.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.awt.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.misc.** {*;}
```