# Android Proguard error with Google Drive API

Tags: android, proguard

I stated using Google Drive API in my project.. Every thing works fine if i run the project on phone using the debug keystore.

when i try to create a signed APK, proguard throws me the following error

```
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] Warning: there were 224 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-10-07 12:59:01 - My Project]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I also tried adding the following into proguard-project.txt

```
-dontwarn org.apache.harmony.**
-dontwarn javax.activation.**
```

If I add the above, APK is created, but the APP crashes on launch

can anyone please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing classes that aren't part of the Android runtime. Either remove the classes referencing them, or if you just want to suppress the warnings, try adding

`-dontwarn java.awt.**,java.beans.**` to your proguard config.

Additional info in the [ProGuard Troubleshooting Guide](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html).

Comment: If we use this, APK will be created.. but after we install.. App crashes!

Comment: Are you using javamail? If so, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434699/android-javamail-and-proguard