# what proguard rules should I use to make javaMailApi work perfectly?

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-r8

I'm using JavaMail API to send emails from my android app with OAUTH2. App working fine withOut enabling proGuard.

if I set `minifyEnabled true` in my build.gradle file my app size reduced but failed to send emails from my app.
These are the dependencies I used in my app for sending emails.

```
//Java mail Api for Android
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
```

I had seen some questions in StackOverflow but not working for me. Any suggestions please..

Comment: Use this answer:
[JavaMail with Proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434699/android-javamail-and-proguard)

Comment: @FarukhTariq I'm getting Unresolved class name error while using those proguard rules. Do you have some other solution?

Comment: Could you please post the errors you are seeing when using the proposed rules? And could you also mention which version of Android Studio/AGP you are using, and whether you use ProGuard or R8 for shrinking?