# Open source Java CORBA ORB on Android?

Tags: java, android, corba, jacorb

There is some info out there suggesting that it is possible to use CORBA on Android, [concretely with Jacorb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432912/obfuscating-android-app-with-corba).

However, it seems that [officially](http://www.jacorb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=920) there is no support for such thing.

Is there any fork of JacORB that supports it? Are there any other open source Java ORBs that work on Android?

Comment: I would like to recommend you to raise this on the JacORB list.

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen the same question was raised on the [list](http://lists.spline.inf.fu-berlin.de/pipermail/jacorb-developer/2013-May/000296.html) some months ago without much success

Comment: Why JacORB? Doesn't Android support CORBA out of the box? Java does.

Comment: @EJP Android does not support Java SE APIs, but only a subset of them, plus its own stuff: http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html . Neither CORBA or RMI are part of those.

Comment: I meant "does not support ALL Java SE APIs"

Answer (score 1):

JacORB 2 could be compiled without rmi option for Android. JacORB 3 needs to be patched. See [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.corba.jacorb.devel/7128) for further information or post to the JacORB mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to supply patches to JacORB to get it work for Android they would be welcome. Please post to the JacORB developer list.