# Corba with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, corba

I'm trying to start a new project in android studio Which requires CORBA (Common Object Request Broker Architecture) standard, so I searched about it, I found this library, and I added it in my project, but it seems nothing change, I think I should write something in the dependencies before !! and I can't found any documentation about dependencies in android studio of CORBA, so any help please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORBA support is no longer part of the standard Java platform (deprecated in Java 9, and removed in Java 11).  CORBA has never been part of the standard Android platform.

The following leads may help:

- [Open source Java CORBA ORB on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576476) talks about trying to get JacORB to work on Android.
- OIS' ORBExpress (commercial) product is available for Android: [product link](http://www.ois.com/Products/orbexpress-for-android.html).
- [TAO](https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO) and [TAOX11](https://www.taox11.org) have been ported to Android in the past so both would be worth the try